# jquery validation issue

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to match strings that contain 4 characters separated by |

Works fine in java when I use `"(\\w{1,4})(\\|(\\w{1,4}))*"`

When I use same pattern in jquery it does not match:

```
$.validator.addMethod("nameId",function(value,element){
return this.optional(element) || /^(\\w{1,4})(\\|(\\w{1,4}))*$/i.test(value);
},"Please enter valid input.");
```

Can anybody let me know how to do this in jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is because you include the double backslashes. If you change `\\w` to `\w` and etc., does that fix the problem?

Comment: The simplest way to do it would be to add `\s*` to the beginning and end of the regex (i.e., after the `^` and before the `$`). The only downside is I don't think that's the most *efficient* way to check for it.

Answer (score 2):

The double backslash is needed to create a literal backslash in the string. By itself, the backslash is treated as *escape character* inside a string. In order to create a literal `\`, you need to escape it `\\`.

As you have a regex *literal* in JS and not a string, you don't need to escape it:

```
/^(\w{1,4})(\|(\w{1,4}))*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a single `\` as the escape character:

```
/^(\w{1,4})(\|(\w{1,4}))*$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexes in Javascript are first-class, not a string, so you don't need to double the backslashes (this results in literal backslashes).

Try this instead

```
/^(\w{1,4})(\|(\w{1,4}))*$/i
```

Edit:
This is not directly related to the question, but some other improvements for this regex:

- since you are only testing for a match and not using it, you should probably use non-capturing parentheses
- the parentheses around \w and the repetition are not needed

Applying these changes would result in the slightly faster (and in my opinion more readable)

```
/^\w{1,4}(?:\|\w{1,4})*$/i
```

I created a quick comparison here: http://jsperf.com/capturing-vs-non-capturing-regex-parentheses